# Is there a way to increase the url length handled by IIS 7.0?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a url being requested from ie 10 that is 2500 characters long (it shows up on the f12 tools as the complete url, without being truncated) but inside my aspx page the query string that comes in is truncated. I have already tried adding these to the web.config

```
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" maxUrl="2147483647" maxQueryString="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Is there any other setting on IIS 7 that limits the length of the url? Is there a way to see all the requests that are coming into IIS so that I know what's coming in is not truncated? (I tried wireshark, there is no easy way to get the url from it. The traffic is https)

Comment: Any particular reason not to use `POST` instead?

Comment: Doing a post is the backup option. I am guessing the person who originally wrote the code used a get because no state was being changed in the operation. It was a pure fetch for display.